# If meta value is empty do not display php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm displaying woocommerce meta values on my product page - I need to not display a value when the client doesn't enter anything in a particular field. Here's what I'm using:

```
<li>Weight: <strong><?php echo get_post_meta
( $post->ID, '_text_field_weight', true );?> Ct</strong>.</li>
```

I was trying to get this work using the "if empty" as following but with no luck:

```
<?php if(!empty($post->ID, '_text_field_weight')) { ?>
<li>Weight: <strong>
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_weight', true );?> Ct</strong>.
</li><?php } ?>
```

Am I even close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work.

```
$someValue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_weight', true );

if(!($someValue == null || $someValue == '')){
    echo "<li>Weight: <strong>{$someValue} Ct</strong>.</li>";
}
```

The above will check and see if $someValue has any value, if it doesn't display nothing, if it does display the contents of $someValue.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly - thank you very very muchly. You really saved me there:)